# Hadoop Mapreduce word count Program

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am new to Hadoop. Below is  my code. I am getting the following error message when i run the Jar.

Input file (wordcount.txt) => this file is stored in "/home/cloudera/SK_JAR/jsonFile/wordcount.txt" path

Hello Hadoop, Goodbye Hadoop.

```
   package com.main;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

    public static class Map extends Mapper {
        private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
        private Text word = new Text();

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            String line = value.toString();
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
                context.write(word, one);
            }
        }
     } 

     public static class Reduce extends Reducer {

        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
          throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable val : values) {
                sum += val.get();
            }
            context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
     }


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IllegalArgumentException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException, InterruptedException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

Configuration conf = new Configuration();


        Job job = new Job(conf, "wordcount");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));


//      job.waitForCompletion(true);
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ?  0 : 1);


    }

}
```

Following is the error message.**Can some one please help me on this?**

let me know if you guys need more details..

```
hadoop jar Wordcount.jar WordCount '/home/cloudera/SK_JAR/jsonFile/wordcount.txt'  output

Error in laoding args file.java.io.FileNotFoundException: WordCount (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
    at com.main.mainClass.main(mainClass.java:28)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.run(RunJar.java:221)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:136)
```

Comment: how did you create Wordcount.jar ?

Comment: I exported the project from eclipse as "runnable jar".

Comment: Can you provide your Hadoop command by which you are running this jar? It seems it is not able to get your input file wordcount.txt.

Comment: @User007 try my answer

Comment: @Sangeeta : Below is the Hadoop command which i have executed
  ===>             
hadoop jar Wordcount.jar WordCount '/home/cloudera/SK_JAR/jsonFile/wordcount.txt'  output

Comment: @User007 Your command should be of this form :
**$HADOOP_HOME/bin/hadoop jar jar_name.jar <input_file> <output_dir>**

In your command after providing jar you have written WordCount and after that i think you have provided the inputfile. It should be file name after providing jarname.

Comment: @Sangreeta According to the documentation, the main class is needed. https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/CommandsManual.html#jar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `hadoop jar Wordcount.jar WordCount`

Your main class is part of a package `com.main`therefore `com.main.WordCount` is needed to start your class.

You can open your JAR file as a ZIP file to verify if you can find `com/main/WordCount$Map.class` within it. If it is not there, then Eclipse is building your JAR wrong.

I might suggest you learn Maven, Gradle, or SBT to build a JAR rather than your IDE. In production, these are the tools commonly used to bundle Hadoop JAR files.

Comment: 17/10/31 19:50:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1509466664631_0006_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class com.main.WordCount$Map not found
 at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2199)

Comment: Well, I might suggest you can try find the difference here https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/MapReduceTutorial.html#Source_Code For starters, you are missing types on your Map and Reduce classes

Comment: Cool. Now, use that as your template

Answer (score -1):

It seems main class file was not mentioned with your runnable jar file.

If you are using Eclipse to create jar file then follow below steps to create Wordcount.jar.

> Right click on Project -> Export JAR file -> Click Next - > Uncheck
>   all other resources. Then provide path for exporting .jar file ->
>   Click Next -> Keep options selected -> Click Next and Finish. [reference](http://www.shabdar.org/hadoop-java/138-how-to-create-and-run-eclipse-project-with-a-mapreduce-sample.html)

Comment: When i Uncheck all other resources, Next button got disabled.

Comment: @cricket_007 i think the error "Error in laoding args file.java.io.FileNotFoundException: WordCount (No such file or directory)" clearly says Wordcount is not found and it is the main class.. i just gave the other way for exporting jar instead of runnable jar..

Comment: There is a difference between Class not found and File not found